# itextsharp ARIALUNI.TTF copy on hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext, special-characters

My application is MVC4 c#, I am using itextsharp to generate PDF files.  To print special characters ≥, I use:

```
string ARIALUNI_TFF = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF");
var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(ARIALUNI_TFF, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
var f = new Font(bf, 10, Font.NORMAL);
```

When I published the application on a shared hosting server, got this error:

```
C:\Windows\Fonts\ARIALUNI.TTF not found as file or resource.
```

Copied the file to Content directory and tried to use:

```
string ARIALUNI_TFF1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/ARIALUNI.TFF");
// FontFactory.Register(ARIALUNI_TFF1);
var bf1 = BaseFont.CreateFont(ARIALUNI_TFF1, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
var f1 = new Font(bf1, 10, Font.NORMAL);
```

I get the following error:

```
ARIALUNI.TFF' with 'Identity-H' is not recognized.
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced:

```
string fontpath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/ARIALUNI.TFF");I replaced:
    var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    var f = new Font(bf, 10, Font.NORMAL);
```

with

```
string fontpath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/");
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath + "ARIALUNI.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font f = new Font(bf, 10, Font.NORMAL);
```

It worked.

Comment: Using this answer I am getting NullReferenceException. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This really is strange issue I faced . Posting my solution. I needed to register this font to `FontFactory` and retrieve this font from factory using `GetFont`

Try this

```
    string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/ArialUni.TFF");
    iTextSharp.text.Font fnt = new iTextSharp.text.Font();
    FontFactory.Register(path, "CustomAriel");
    fnt = FontFactory.GetFont("CustomAriel", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 10,Font.NORMAL);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: table1.AddCell(new Phrase("≥60", (fnt)));  This worked well when I used Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF").  Thanks

Comment: Instead of that symbol could you try using a Unicode escape sequence? '\u2265'