# Unity3d iTextSharp arabic text formatting

Tags: c#, pdf, unity-game-engine, itext, arabic

I am using iTextSharp for PDF generating in Unity3d.

**EDIT**

Here is the code, but I am getting an empty PDF document:

```
    void createPDF()
    {
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A1, 5, 5, 5, 5);
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("TestPDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        string fontPath =  "C:\\windows\\Fonts\\arialuni.ttf";
        BaseFont basefont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        iTextSharp.text.Font tahomaFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(basefont, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
        PdfContentByte cb = wri.DirectContent;
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
        Phrase myText = new Phrase(GameObject.Find("TextPlay").GetComponent<TextMesh>().text);
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, 34, 750, 580, 317, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        ct.Go();

        doc.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you that the font `ArialJezici.ttf` can't be used with encoding `Identity_H`, hence you will have to replace that font with another one, for instance with `ArialUni.ttf`.

Actually, this should work:

```
BaseFont bf = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Note that you need to provide the correct path. I don't think you're doing that in your example.

If the above snippet doesn't work, see [itextsharp ARIALUNI.TTF copy on hosting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728381/itextsharp-arialuni-ttf-copy-on-hosting-server) for an alternative example on how to do this.

Note that Arabic ligatures only work in the context of `PdfPCell` and `ColumnText` objects, they do not work in a `Paragraph` added to the `Document` because you can not set the run direction of a `Paragraph`. You can only set the run direction of a cell or a column.

If you do not set your run direction, the Arabic text will be written from left to right and no ligatures will be made, resulting in something this is not correct Arabic.

**Contrary to the rules on StackOverflow, the original question was changed, resulting in my answer no longer being the answer to the new version of the question. This is an update with the anser to the current question:**

With the `BaseFont` created in the first part of my answer, create a `Font`:

```
Font font = new Font(bf, 20);
```

Now create a `ColumnText` object and provide coordinates that fit your page:

```
ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
column.SetSimpleColumn(36, 730, 569, 36);
```

If these coordinates *do not fit your page*, your content will be added to the file, but you won't see anything because the content is *outside the visible area of the page*.

For Arabic text, it is important that you set the run direction (I don't see you doing that anywhere):

```
column.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
```

Now add the content:

```
column.AddElement(new Paragraph(GameObject.Find("TextPlay").GetComponent<TextMesh>().text));
column.Go();
```

This works for me, see the [Java example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=210) or [corresponding C# example](http://kuujinbo.info/itextinaction2ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter11&ex=Ligatures2), resulting in this file: [ligatures_2.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part3/chapter11/ligatures_2.pdf)

That file shows the Arabic text "لورانس العرب" three times. The first time, the characters are not in the right order. The second time, the characters are in the right order, but no ligatures are being made. The third time, it is shown correctly.

Comment: Actually I am not sure. Font is in folder `Assets/Fonts`, and I did try `/Assets/Fonts/ArialUni.tff`, `Assets/Fonts/ArialUni.tff`, `/Fonts/ArialUni.tff`, `Fonts/ArialUni.tff`

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with C# to tell you how to load a file from a relative path. Try with an absolute path first to determine whether you're confronted with an iTextSharp problem. If it works when using an absolute path, then the problem is not caused by iTextSharp, and you should look at C#: how to define the path to a file in my Assets directory.

Comment: Yeah, but when I build it for iOS or Android I don't think it will work.

Comment: That's true, but first you want to debug your code. In order to debug your code, you need to find out if the culprit is iTextSharp or the fact that you are using the wrong path. Maybe you need to replace `/` by `\\\` in iTextSharp... I don't know, I'm not a C# developer. I only want to help you determine if the problem is caused by your font, by iTextSharp, or something else.

Comment: This will provide the path to the font `Application.dataPath + "/Fonts/arialuni.tff"` but again I get the same error.

Comment: The font arialuni.ttf can be found here `C:\\windows\\Fonts\\arialuni.ttf`. Do me a favor and test this *first* instead of avoiding to listen to my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't want to avoid the answer. Path is ok, but the PDF is empty now. I did use this:

`PdfContentByte cb = wri.DirectContent;
  ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
  Phrase myText = new Phrase(GameObject.Find("TextPlay").GetComponent<TextMesh>().text);
  ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, 34, 750, 580, 317, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
  ct.Go();`

Comment: You are not defining the run direction. It would be better if you create a new question so that one can better read your code. Now it's presented in a single line.

Comment: check this question that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080741/convert-arabicunicode-content-html-or-xml-to-pdf-using-itextsharp